# What is the difference in work and responsibility between all Web Development Job's designations/Title?

Tags: user-interface, accessibility, user-experience

What is the difference in work, software/coding/programing/designing skills, and responsibility between all these Job designations/Title?

I found all these terms in jobs posted on linkedin.com and on various job sites under category IT - Software. when i search for jobs in Web development.

Graphic Designer

Digital Designer

Web Designer

Creative Designer

Interaction Designer

UI Designer

Design Director

UX Designer

---

Web Developer

UI Developer

UI Engineer

Software Engineer

Software Developer

Back-end developer

---

Web Producer

Creative Producer

Creative Director

Multimedia Director

---

Front-end developer

XHTML/CSS developer

Front-end Coder

---

UX architect

UX Strategist

UX Consultant

Usability Analyst

QA Analyst

Information Architect

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any standard definition for any of these titles. There is absolutely no regulation on the profession of programming so you can be called anything you want or anything you get your company to call you.

Comment: but then how we can know , for which job we can apply for. I'm mainly confused between Web Designer,UI Designer,UX Designer,UI Developer,UI Engineer,Web Producer,Front-end developer,XHTML/CSS developer,Front-end Coder.

Comment: In general job postings list the skills required, and that is what you should be looking for.